# .click function passes When step, but isn't actually clicking the element in the browser

Tags: cucumberjs, wdio-v5

I'm currently trying to script some automation tests.

I've hit a block with what should be a simple checkbox click...

The issue is the test run passes the step, but in the browser the "click" hasn't actually occurred.

POM

```js
    optionClick(optionValue){
        const option = $('//input[@type="checkbox"]').$('..').$('label').$('//span[contains(text(), "'+optionValue+'")]');
        option.waitForDisplayed(2000);
        const optionSelect = $('//input[@type="checkbox"]').$('..').$('label').$('//span[contains(text(), "'+optionValue+'")]');
        optionSelect.click();
    }
```

Feature is - And I select the 'Create' option

the html element I'm trying to click is as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The click function is asynchronous. If you don't do an await or wrap the click call  in a promise then the action will take place synchronously meaning your test will move on and will probably finish before the click actually takes place.

What you need to do is:

```
        await optionSelect.click();
```

Comment: I'm working sync rather than async :/ 
Is there a different function to use instead? I've got .click working elsewhere in other methods, so not sue why it's not working here...

Comment: Resolved the issue. Thanks for your suggestion though :)

Comment: You could also just do it through a return, and it should execute